# Is it possible sniff all packets on your own wifi subnet using npm package cap?

Tags: raspberry-pi, libpcap, packet-sniffers

I've installed an npm package on a Pi that uses mscdex/cap (cap) to sniff packets for both udp and tcp on specific ports over wlan0.  Cap defaults to promiscuous mode and I want to view packets being sent to another computer on the same wireless subnet.  So, how can I listen to packets sent to a port on another computer/IP address within the same wifi subnet?

Comment: Do you have any code that you can share? It looks like this is based on libpcap/npcap, so  you should be able to capture wireless traffic, but you need to specify the correct interface. Based on the documentation though, it looks like this library (https://github.com/mscdex/cap) is designed to parse ethernet, but not 802.11.

Comment: Well... I think you've answered the question without code... here is is anyway.  I edited the post.  I could have replaced the IP with wlan0 but it looks like that package won't work well with 802.11.  Question will be which one does and is also syntactically close to cap?

Comment: Good point. I'll move it to an answer. Questions asking for recommendations are unfortunately against the guidelines of stack overflow.

Comment: That said, https://github.com/node-pcap/node_pcap uses node and has wireless examples

Comment: That looks like it should work.  It was easy enough to set up and test but I can't seem to get the filter right to capture a specific port on a specific host.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

npm cap (github.com/mscdex/cap) uses libpcap/npcap to capture packets, so you should be able to capture wireless traffic. However, in order to capture wireless traffic, you need to specify the correct interface (something like `wlan0`, and will depend on your machine).

Based on the documentation for this project, the only link-layer protocol it is designed to parse is ethernet, not 802.11.

Comment: You were correct on using that package.  Unfortunately, I'm trying to do this with a Pi 3+ and it doesn't support monitor mode.  So, I disabled the internal wifi and used a USB adapter that did.  Now, when it opens pcap, the wifi dies... but that's for another post! ;-)